# Error occurred when importing DECIMAL data with Python Api

Tags: python, decimal, dolphindb, appender

DolphinDB  server version : 2.00.9.1 2023.02.20 ; linux64

python==3.7

DDB package version : 1.30.21.1

**Problem Description:**

I want to use `ddb.tableAppender()` to write a Python dataframe to a DolphinDB table. A column in the table is of type DECIMAL. But after uploading, the data is changed.

[image]

Comment: I noticed that this also occurred for your id_1, and both only has a decimal precision of 3 compared to the rest which has a precision of 4, and after transferring all of them have a precision of 4. Could this be related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Python API for DolphinDB (5.4.2)](https://github.com/dolphindb/api_python3/blob/master/README.md#542-data-type-conversion), when uploading tables containing objects of `Python decimal.Decimal()`, you must ensure that all values in the columns of DECIMAL  type have the same decimal digits. Otherwise, it will return a value with the same digits as the first row of value. Your first row of data has four decimal digits, so error will occur when you upload data with 3 decimal digits.

To solve the problem, you can try the following script:

```
price_list = [Decimal(str(round(random.uniform(1, 1000),4))).quantize(decimal.Decimal("0.0000")) for _ in range(10)] + [Decimal(str(round(random.uniform(1, 100),4))).quantize(decimal.Decimal("0.0000")) for _ in range(10)]
```